# jQuery clickevent from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working clickevent handler (don't know if it's the right word for it) on a page which uses show/hide (like tabs) if you click on one of the on-page links. This works perfectly, but now I walk into another issue.

When I link to one of the tabs from a different page, eg. /page-slug/#tabtoshow it won't show the right tab, it just shows the first (open) tab. I want it to show the right tab when a URL contains the same id, eg #tabtoshow. The tabs will have the same id as the link.

This is my current script.

```
$(function() {
    $(".elevator a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});        
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="#ondernemen"]').click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $('#ondernemen').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#groeien"]').click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $('#groeien').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#spelen"]').click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $('#spelen').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $('#ontdekken').slideDown(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
        $('#groeien').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    });
    $('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
    $('a[href="#ontdekken"]').parent('.label').addClass("active");
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes @CameronTinker, I am

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving to another physical page, not a virtual page, you will need to handle the hash on the new page. You'd need to access [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).hash or `location.pathname` and do something based on the hash value. You could handle it similarly to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    displayTab(location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had some repetition, I have written a more general version for you. Also, I have used `location.hash` to determine what tab to activate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selector = "#ondernemen, #ontdekken, #groeien, #spelen";
    $(".elevator a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
    $(selector).click(function() {
        var that = this;
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $(selector).each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("id") !== $(that).attr("id")) {
                $(this).slideUp(1000);
            }
        });
        $(this).slideDown(1000);
    });
    $('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
    $(location.hash).parent('.label').addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Lajos! Unfortunately this won't work because some elements need to slideDown. With this code they will only slide up. Perhaps it's best to take a quick look at the website, so you can see how my 'tab nav' works? The right page is www.gastouderfabriek.nl/trainingen/

Comment: I think we need to add this for each element, like if `$('a[href="#spelen"]').click(function()` and if `$(location.hash)` has the right has, do the stuff with slideUp and slideDown. Do you think as well? Only, I don't know how to code this... Could you help me out?

Comment: I have just seen you have commented. When I have answered I was pretty tired, so I did not see you are calling the slideDown function.

Comment: Also, note, that your dynamic-captions.css is failed to load, you might be missing some of your design.

Comment: Also, give your anchors some ids, it is messy to select them by href, also, from your code we can see you have assumed that they have ids (ex: $('#ondernemen').slideDown(1000);), but they did not have one. So, fix your html (add the ids to the anchors), apply my code and fix it if needed (I have not tested it), correct your reference to the css file and come back here and tell us what happened :)

Comment: Thanks @Lajos for your time! Unfortunately it doesn't work, even after I provided the anchors with an ID. I agree that the code is messy, but it does work for now. I solved it with `if(window.location.hash == "#groeien") {...}` etc. Maybe I'll get back to this post later after my vacation. Thanks again!

Comment: "does not work" does not describe your problem, but I am happy you have sorted out all problems.